# For an $n$ x $n$ and $n$ x $m$ matrices A and B, respectively, show $rank[B$ $AB$ $A^2B$ $...$ $A^{n-1}B]=rank[B$ $AB$ $A^2B$ $...$ $A^{n-1}B$ $A^nB]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking for help or any advice on proving this.

For an $n$ x $n$ and $n$ x $m$ matrices A and B, respectively, show

$rank[B$ $AB$ $A^2B$ $...$ $A^{n-1}B] = rank[B$ $AB$ $A^2B$ $...$ $A^{n-1}B$ $A^nB]$.

I know I am supposed to use Cayley-Hamilton Theorem to rewrite $A^nB$ in terms of ($B, AB, A^2B, ..., A^{n-1}B$). I also know that the columns of $A^nB$ are a linear combination of the previous matrices columns.

However the part I am stuck on is that I'm assuming that $A$ is a $2$ x $2$ matrix and B is a $2$ x $1$ matrix for simplicity which would make $A^nB$ a $2$ x $1$ matrix which the Cayley-Hamilton matrix doesn't apply to.

Comment: If $A$ is $n$ x $n$ and $B$ is $n$ x $m$ that makes $AB$ an $n$ x $m$ matrix, and so the columns of the matrix $[B$ $AB$ $A^2B$ $...$ $A{n-1}B]$ becomes a combination of each of the products of the matrices, so I don't think the products are meaningless if $n\ne m$.

Comment: $A^2B$ = $A(AB)$ and $AB$ is a $2$ x $1$ matrix so you can multiply $A$ by $AB$ and so on and so forth for each power of A.

Comment: It was not clear to me that these are columns of a matrix and not just a product of matrices! With that clarification it's trivial: by C-H the last $m$ columns $A^nB$ depend on the first $nm$ columns.

Comment: Yes sorry I should have clarified! And okay so just so I make sure I understand what you are saying, since the last $m$ columns of $A^nB$ depend on the first $nm$ columns, that means the first $nm$ columns are the only ones that are linearly independent making the rank's equal?

Comment: Oh I see, we use C-H on $A^n$ and then multiply by $B$. Thank you so much that helped me to clarify things.